# How to read the txt file data into arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

This following data is inside the Admin.txt file

id, username, password, name, email, contactNumber, icNumber

```
AD001|admin|admin|admin|admin@gmail.com|0123456789|931245678976
AD002|jeff|jeff|jefferyleo|jefferyleo@gmail.com|12345678790|941457431246
```

how should I read these data into an arraylist??

```
List<Admin> adminList = new ArrayList<Admin>();
```

This is the arrayList that I decalred.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Admin.txt"));
String strLine;
while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
{
     String[] values = strLine.split("|");
     adminList.add(new Admin());
}
```

Comment: Read a Java IO tutorial.

Comment: I have tried using Scanner and BufferedReader to do it, but it seems like doesn't work.

Comment: @jefferyleo, post what you've tried.  Give us a snippet of code to review, and the exact errors you're seeing.

Comment: BufferedReader.readLine() and String.split("\|")

Comment: @bedwyr
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Admin.txt"));
String strLine;
while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    String[] values = strLine.split("|");
    adminList.add(new Admin());
}

is this means i already read the text file into arraylist?

Comment: @jefferyleo You're close. Add a parameter to your `Admin` constructor to take a `String[]` and pass in `values`. Then in the constructor loop through the array and initialize your fields. `id = values[0];`, `username = values[1];`, etc.

Comment: You said you have tried, could you please post your code. It would be good learning for you while others comment on your code to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this code can help you

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Admin.txt"));
      ArrayList<Admin> al = new ArrayList<Admin>();
      String line = null;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Admin admin = new Admin();
        String lines[] = line.split("|");
        /*adjust accordingly
        admin.setName(lines[0]);
        admin.setUser(lines[1]);
            ....*/
        al.add(admin);          
      }
      br.close();
}
```

Comment: I'd argue that it's better to pass the `lines[]` in to the `Admin` constructor and have the constructor configure the `Admin` instance. The way it is here after the line `Admin admin = new Admin();` the  `admin` instance isn't completely initialized. Doing it this way also forces you to make the fields in the `Admin` object mutable, which should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @Mike B what if you pass the lines[] into the admin constructor? It's the better way to do?

Comment: In my opinion it's better to pass the `lines[]` in.

Comment: @MikeB so I should do like al.add(lines[0],lines[1],lines[2]...); ??

Comment: No, like I showed in the answer below. `al.add(new Admin(lines));`

Comment: @MikeB But there's shows an error, it mentions that no suitable constructor found for Admin class

Comment: @jefferyleo You have to write the constructor, like I show in the other answer.

Comment: @MikeB I wrote like this...but it seems inside the arraylist showing the weird value...
adminList.add(new Admin(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5], values[6]));

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor to your `Admin` class like this but with fields for all your data:

```
public class Admin {
    private final String id, username, password, name, email, contactNumber, icNumber;
    public Admin (String[] values) {
        this.id = values[0];
        this.username = values[1];
        this.password = values[2];
        this.name = values[3];
        this.email = values[4];
        this.contactNumber = values[5];
        this.icNumber = values[6];
    }
}
```

Note that this isn't meant to be your entire `Admin` class, you only need to modify the constructor to look like the one here.

Then in your loop do this instead:

```
adminList.add(new Admin(values));
```

Comment: what if I want to do it in an event handler and I want to access the attributes of admin class? I tried to re-declared those attributes, but it shows an error